# Single Table Inheritance (STI) with a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm pretty new to Doctrine, so any general advice is welcome. I'm trying to achieve the following:

A page can have both videos and photos. Both are media and share properties, so I thought Single Table Inheritance makes sense. Here are the relevant parts of my setup:

**Page**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Page {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="page", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection|Media[]
     */
    protected $media;

    /**
     * @return Media[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getMedia()
    {
        return $this->media;
    }
}
```

**Media**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="media")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="media_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"video" = "Video", "photo" = "Photo"})
 */
abstract class Media {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="media")
     */
    protected $page;
}
```

**Photo**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Photo extends Media {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $exif;
}
```

**Video**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Video extends Media {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $length;
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but -and this is my question- how do I fetch all `Photo`s or `Video`s of a page. I've tried adding things like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="page", cascade={"persist"})
 * @var ArrayCollection|Photo[]
 */
protected $photos;
```

to `Page`, but this results in a schema error, since it doesn't have an inverse defined on Photo. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply filter to the media collection

```
class Page {
    .....
    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->getMedia()->filter(
            function($media) {
                return $media instanceof Photo;
            }
        );
    }

    public function getVideos()
    {
        return $this->getMedia()->filter(
            function($media) {
                return $media instanceof Video;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, it will fetch all medias in a single `select` query, instantiate both Photos and Videos, and then filter the result. It may affect performance, but you may benefit from doctrine cache, depending on your scenario.

If performance is a key, you may need to implement a custom methods in `PageRepository` to actually fetch only subset of medias using `instance of` dql as described in [Query the Type](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#query-the-type).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for naming the pros and cons + giving an alternative solution using a Repository.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by using a `join` on the specific subclass:

```
$queryBuilder->select('m')
   ->from('Media', 'm')
   ->join('Photo', 'p', 'WITH', 'm.id = p.id')
   ->where('m.page = :page_id')
   ->setParameter('page_id', $pageId);
```

Comment: Valid answer, but I like Alex' answer better since it fits my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have a single `$media` property on your `Page` class which maps to a superclass. You will have to have a property per class. See the [note in the Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html):

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and
>   persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be
>   unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many
>   associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all.
>   Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped
>   superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For
>   further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance
>   features have to be used.

Comment: Makes sense, except that in this case I'm not using a mapped superclass, but STI. The Media object is in fact an entity, so the quoted docs don't apply. Other than that, great answer.